# Developing Visual Studio Universal Project - How to extract text from sequential named TextBoxes in for loop

Tags: visual-c++, win-universal-app

I have a problem with the following code which I thought would extract user input from sequential TextBoxes on a form:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"
#include <iostream>  // for std::cout and std::cin
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
{
    int grid[9][9] = { 0 }; // virtual array filled with zeros
        //put numbers in array
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; ++row)//step through all rows
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; ++col) //step through all columns
        {
            row = row + 1; // text box names suffixes are 11 to 19
            col - col + 1;
                std::string r_str = std::to_string(row);// turn row number into text
            std::string c_str = std::to_string(col);//turn column nuber into text
            std::string texnum = "Tex" + r_str + c_str;// eg "Tex11" //compile textbox name
            String^ str_input = texnum->Text; //get Platform::String from textBox
            std::wstring wsstr(str_input->Data());//Convert Platform::String to String
            int n = std::stoi(wsstr);//Convert String to Integer
            grid[row][col] = n; //put text from texbox in array as a number
        }
}
```

On the line 
String^ str_input = texnum->Text;

At the TexBox Identifier of texnum it gives an error of Expression must have a pointer or handle type. If I replace it with an actual Textbox name Tex11 there is no Error but then it only extract text from one box.
I need a way to get text from a TextBox using a string variable instead of the actual string.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ^ Makes it a managed Variable. For more info see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JKOgBMAHdE (I don't understand but that's what the teacher says.

Comment: this is a C# operation not C++. C# and C++ are different languages, you also probably include header  "MainPage.xaml.h" that is not a C++ header. This cannot compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use the string to try to get the Text property, in that case, it is only a string instead of TextBox object. So you need to first get the TextBox control by the name string you get and then get the Text property by the TextBox.

You can try the following code to use the FindName method to get the TextBox object, the "MyPage" is the parent view of TextBox(e.g. StackPanel). In addition, the FindName method needs to be passed the PlatForm::String^ type, it's easy to convert std::wstring to PlatForm::String^, so it's better to only use std::wstring type instead of std::string.

```
int grid[9][9] = { 0 }; // virtual array filled with zeros
//put numbers in array
for (int row = 0; row < 9; ++row)//step through all rows
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; ++col) //step through all columns
    {
        row = row + 1; // text box names suffixes are 11 to 19
        col - col + 1;

        std::wstring r_str = std::to_wstring(row);// turn row number into text
        std::wstring c_str = std::to_wstring(col);//turn column nuber into text
        std::wstring texnum = L"texnum" + r_str + c_str;
        Platform::String^ aa = ref new Platform::String(texnum.c_str());
        TextBox^ elment = (TextBox ^)MyPage->FindName(ref new Platform::String(texnum.c_str()));
        String^ str_input = elment->Text;
        std::wstring wsstr(str_input->Data());
        int n = std::stoi(wsstr);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Much appreciated. Your code has resolved my Issue. There are a couple of typos so Just in case anyone else requires the answer I will post my final code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code (The StackPanel is named FirstLine)

```
void universal::MainPage::Solve_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
int grid[9][9] = { 0 }; // virtual array filled with zeros
//put numbers in array
for (int row = 0; row < 9; ++row)//step through all rows
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; ++col) //step through all columns
    {
        row = row + 1; // text box names suffixes are 11 to 19
        col = col + 1;

        std::wstring r_str = std::to_wstring(row);// turn row number into text
        std::wstring c_str = std::to_wstring(col);//turn column nuber into text
        std::wstring texnum = L"texnum" + r_str + c_str;
        Platform::String^ aa = ref new Platform::String(texnum.c_str());
        TextBox^ elment = (TextBox^)FirstLine->FindName(aa);
        String^ str_input = elment->Text;
        std::wstring wsstr(str_input->Data());
        int n = std::stoi(wsstr);

    }
```